# Can we expand numbers on the left to produce irrational numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, number-systems

I have seen examples of irrational numbers that are expanded on the right, after the decimal point:

e.g. $\pi = 3.14159265...$

But can we expand numbers on the left side as well?

e.g. Is $82757395734548...5473987349857348.0$ with digits bijective to $\mathbb{N}$ a number?

Syntactically, does an element of a free monoid with the set of generators being the decimal basis represent an irrational number or any number at all in decimal basis? Where can I find more about these numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you look into [p-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), which is the most well-known way to make sense of "numbers notated with an infinity of digits to the left". But it's not *exactly* what you're proposing here.

Your idea about monoids is a red herring, I'm afraid. The free monoid contains only *finite* words, which in this context encode the ordinary finite integers.

And notice that "3.14159265..." is not really *syntax*. The real decimal expansion of $\pi$ is an infinitary object that can't be written down in full, so "3.14159265..." is either just an evocative hint of the real thing or a practical approximation.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on monoids, I did not realize that the words were only finite although arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 4):

What you find is called a $p$-adic number.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Comment: For $p=10$ maybe?

Comment: Of course, not! But I don't think that OP wondered just decimals.